# In Azure Boards, how to prevent team from changing priority of user stories in the sprint backlog?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

As a Scrum Master, I want to make sure that my team doesn't "accidentally" change the priority of User Stories on my **Sprints** page's **backlog** view, so that my work is not unnecessarily increased.

How do I set the permissions so that only a select group of people can drag up/down the User Stories?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The permissions in TFS aren't granular enough to prevent this specific field from being changed.

You'd need to use `witadmin` to set a rule on the `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority` field to be `<READONLY not =""/>` with a team/user group in the `""`; e.g. `READONLY not="[project]\Project Administrators" />`, where you're the only user in that group.

`witadmin` isn't for the faint of heart, so if you're not comfortable editing work item templates, you might just need to wrap their knuckles when they change the priority.

**-- or --**

You're talking about the order of items on the backlog, which would be their **stack rank**. In which case, you'd want to do the same but on the `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank` field.